# Powershell select where attribute exists

Tags: xml, powershell

I have three nodes with the same name but with different attributes. I would like to only select the one where the bar attribute exists.

```
<Test foo="Hello" />
<Test bar="World" />
<Test zed="Goodbye" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use XPath for this:

```
Select-Xml -Path path\to\file.xml -XPath '//Test[@bar]'
```

`//Test` will resolve any `<Test>` nodes anywhere in the tree, `[@bar]` filters them by whether they have a `bar` attribute or not

Comment: The OP requests for @bar. So in this example it should be: //Test[@bar]